# Paste lines in Vim

Tags: 16.10, vim

I've copied 9 lines from a PDF, and I want to past it in Vim. Could anyone be able to tell how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [don't cross post questions](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/paste-lines-in-vim). You should delete this question and hope for an answer on the other one, since this question is more suited for that site anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete the other one and wait for an answer here.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend the other way around.

Comment: Personnally, I'd prefer to keep this question here.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem very little difference :) The dupe that David suggests has an answer by me which borrows from an answer on [vi.se]. :D

Answer (score 1):

There are few options that you can use if you have highlighted the text in the pdf viewer you can do it with middle click of your mouse!

You can also try `"+p` or `"*p` this should also paste content of clipboard!
check this out for more information:

[pasting registers in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Pasting_registers)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>i</kbd> to go into insert mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste

Comment: @DavidFoerster  Hmmm , I think the suggested  duplicate  is slightly different: that one asks to copy from vim to clipboard, this one asks to copy from clipboard to vim.  Also my answer there is different,too, it uses `xclip` , this one just standard keyboard shortcuts. But still, good job finding that one , it might be useful for other users who come accross it :3

Comment: Be careful with Ctrl-Shift-V. If indentation is enabled, the copied text will be indented unlike with `"+p` or `"+-y`. You should do `:set paste` if you want to safely copy stuff as-is with C-S-v